# Final variable from resources file

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

I have an activity with some **final** variables. I extracted their values (let's assume they're all Strings) into a resources file.

The problem:

If I directly assign them on the instantiation (as following):

`private final String PREFERENCE_NAME = getResources().getString(R.string.preference_name);`

I get the following error:

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

I understand the problem; the onCreate() method has not been called yet which means I cannot access context-related methods (`getResources()`).

If I want to assign the value in the onCreate() method of the activity, I get the error `Cannot assign value to final variable 'PREFERENCE_NAME'`

**The question is:** How can I get my final variables to be assigned from the resources file? And if this is not possible, what is the best practice for a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't. Are you sure you need `PREFERENCE_NAME` to be localized ?

Comment: what's stopping you from getting it from your resources as and when you need it?

Comment: @Blackbelt I need to use it in multiple activities; if I for what reason need to change the PREFERENCE_NAME, I'd like to do this from resources.

Comment: @Dreagen multiple calls throughout my code are stopping me from doing so. I wish to call and assign it once while simply referring from the code to the variable to avoid extra calls to the resources files.

Comment: I still don't see the point to have it stored in the resources when it could be a constant referenced by every activity that needs it

Comment: @Blackbelt I personally do agree with you however within this project I am dependent on the demands of others, what means no string literals in the code whatsoever...

Comment: I really don't see the harm in calling to the resources multiple times. If you need to change the value you still only need to do it in one place and as far as I'm aware it's not an expensive call

Comment: You're right @Dreagen. That seems the best solution so far.

Comment: `I am dependent on the demands of others` - even when they make no sense?  Show them this question!  It doesn't matter what you do, there will be a string constant in your code somewhere.  BTW, why don't you just declare it then set in onCreate().  `Final` means you can only assign once, not that you can only assign it when you declare it.

Comment: @Simon the onCreate() method is called multimple times hence not the right place to assign. The constructor has no knowledge of the context as the context is instantiated in the onCreate() method.

Comment: I'll put my suggestion as an answer then you can mark correct if that's what you decide, that way others can easily see what the outcome was

Comment: Did that, thanks. Also, -1? seriously?

Comment: Not sure why -1, question seems reasonable to me. I have +1'd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I think the best thing to do it just make multiple calls to the resources. You still only have to change the value in one place and the call to `getResources()` isn't an expensive one.

Comment: I'll go for this solution. However I'd like to point out for other with a similar problem that this is not the **only** solution.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is that you can't.

Variables declared `final` can only be set when the object is instantiated (i.e. in the constructor or with initialiser code).

Either use `getResources().getString(R.string.preference_name);` all the time or use a non-final variable.

The complex answer is that you can but that you shouldn't.

When you declare a variable `final` the compiler and VM uses this to make optimisations and assumptions. It can do this because the variable is guaranteed to never change. Changing it after it has been initialised can cause really weird bugs so you absolutely should not do that.

Here's how you do it:

```
public class FinalMessage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        FinalMessage f = new FinalMessage("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(f.getMessage());
        f.changeFinalMessage("Hello Mars!");
        System.out.println(f.getMessage());
    }

    private final String message;

    public FinalMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    void changeFinalMessage(String newMessage) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        final Field field = FinalMessage.class.getDeclaredField("message");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        field.set(this, newMessage);
    }

    String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

This will output:

> Hello World!
>   Hello Mars!

Great, so we changed a final variable. No problem right?

Well, take this example instead:

```
public class FinalMessage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        FinalMessage f = new FinalMessage();
        System.out.println(f.getMessage());
        f.changeFinalMessage("Hello Mars!");
        System.out.println(f.getMessage());
    }

    private final String message = "Hello World!";

    void changeFinalMessage(String newMessage) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        final Field field = FinalMessage.class.getDeclaredField("message");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        field.set(this, newMessage);
    }

    String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

This will output:

> Hello World!
>   Hello World!

Wait, what?

The problem is that the compiler can see that the variable `message` is always going to be `"Hello World!"` so it inlines `"Hello World!"` instead of our call to `f.getMessage()`. If you run this in a debugger you will see the debugger reflect the updated message in the instance to `"Hello Mars!"` but since the variable is actually never accessed it won't affect the outcome of the program.

So to summarize: You can update final fields via reflection (granted that there is no [Security Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) present that prevents you from doing it), but you should not do it since it can have very, very weird side-effects.

I am not responsible if your house gets termites or your cat catches on fire if you actually decide to implement this.

Comment: Wow, that was a good read. Thank you for your well explained example and why not to do it. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Use your application context:

1. Create an application class:

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {

       private static Context mContext;

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           mContext = getApplicationContext();
       }

       public static String getStr(int resId) {
           return mContext.getString(resId);
       }

   }
   ```
2. Use it in your manifest:

   ```
   <application
       android:name=".MyApplication"
       ...
   ```
3. Call it anywhere in your application:

   ```
   static final String NAME = MyApplication.getStr(R.string.app_name);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I try to refrain from creating a custom application class so I'll go with the suggestion of Dreagen. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to solve this issue.

The builder is a class that aggregates the data needed to create your object, and when you are done - you just build your class.

In this approach, the data needed to generate the object is also available to the factory, and he can easily create the object, and initialize the `final` field when invoking its constructor.

You will have something like

```
class MyFactory {
   private Resource getResources() { ... }
   public MyObject build() { 
       String perference_name = getResources().getString(R.string.preference_name);
       /...
       return new MyObject(perfence_name ,....);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't instantiate my classes, I have to use onCreate(). I think this doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare it as a final method:

```
private final String PREFERENCE_NAME() {
    return getResources().getString(R.string.preference_name);}
```