# String resource is not passed to Static app Java class

Tags: java, android

I have  tried various ways asked and answered here about this with no luck, such as:
[android how to use string resource in a java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102741/android-how-to-use-string-resource-in-a-java-class)

In an android project I have an app class named configuration, where several static variables are stored and used in my activities etc.

For a

```
public static final String MYVARIABLE
```

I want to load a string value depending on localised language from

```
values/strings.xml
```

I have tried importing:

```
 import com.myappdomain.R
```

Then to get the string

```
context.getString(R.string.my_string_in_values_xml)
```

so that:

```
String FORMYVARIABLE = context.getString(R.string.my_string_in_values_xml);
```

Also I have tried:

```
String FORMYVARIABLE = 
getResources().getString(R.string.my_string_in_values_xml);
```

apk compiles without error, but the string is not passed in the java class producing Fatal exception, in all the java activities that utilise the static string.

Any pointers? I dont want to use extra configuration locales etc in my class just to set a string that already exists in several languages in res/values/strings.xml  unless there is no other way because I want to add/delete/edit them from there.

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913722/final-variable-from-resources-file#targetText=The%20simple%20answer%20is%20that,use%20a%20non%2Dfinal%20variable.

Comment: I have seen that answer, but i dont want to make multiple calls to the resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.cancel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below ,

```
String s = getActivity().getResource().getString(R.string.my_string_in_values_xm);
```

Comment: I dont think  getActivity() exists there

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using couple of techniques.

1.If you really want to keep the variables `final`, you can create a static resource variable in your app class. Like this:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="x.x.x">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    ....


    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        ....
```

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    public static Resources resources;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        resources=getResources();
    }
```

Utility.java

```
public class Utility {


    public static final String TODAY_MUST_BE_BIG= MyApplication.resources.getString(R.string.today_must_be_bigger);
```

2.If it is not mandatory to keep those variables, `final`, the better solution would be to initialize them inside the `Application` class or `MainActivity` class.

Comment: Thank you for start, From your example i understand that I have to do this in all my activities that utilise TODAY_MUST_BE_BIG, correct? I have many activities, classes that use this, that's why I keep them all in a configuration class (I dint plan from the start that I will need localization). I thought that would be a simpler way. However,  I will try your way too.

Comment: @qwertyg not at all! if you follow method 1, you have already the value `TODAY_MUST_BE_BIG`  available to you. if you follow method 2, you have to do it  once, as the values are static, it will remain as long as your app is not stopped.

Comment: sorry, now i get it. And how  can I resolve MultiDexApplication ? It is not recognised

Comment: @qwertyg check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284064/7360848

Comment: In my case it does not work, even if I include the  multidex support library it cannot be resolved. Also I am using minSdkVersion 22 so MultiDexApplication should be enabled by default  as it is stated here:https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle . However, this method does not work for me.

Comment: @qwertyg you have to reference the application class from Manifest, check the updated answer.

Comment: also `MultidexApplication` is not mandatory, you can also simply use `Application` class here and not enable multidex